# Linker Command Fails When Changing From Debug to Release

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I know this is a common error but it's my understanding that there can be many causes. After searching around and trying a few things I have been unable to find something that works for me.

This is all started when I wanted to test to make sure that NSLog() was being surprised correctly in my Release version so I changed the build configuration to Release from Debug under my Run schema. Now I'm getting a link error which points to a file in my unit tests.

I am able to run the unit tests fine so I don't know what the problem is there. Furthermore, why would a release version be trying to compile things in my test folder?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FDSFTP", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FDSFTPTests.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FDSFTPTests)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UICKeyChainStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FDSFTPTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: "why would a release version be trying to compile things in my test folder" Because that is what the Run action in your scheme _says_ to do. Look and see.

Comment: I looked for the keyword 'Release' in my Build Settings and could not find any reference to test. Am I looking in the wrong spot?

Comment: I didn't say build settings. I said scheme. You do know what a scheme is, right? You mentioned it in your question, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to add the file which couldn't be linked above, FDSFTP, to my Compiled Sources for my test Target.

I am still unsure as to why I had to do this for my Release build configuration and not Debug but this solved my problem. I'm guessing that there is a flag somewhere in the Build Settings that makes the difference but I was unable to figure out which one.